# I can't install any package using pip

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Recently I installed Python 2.7 as I wanted to rewrite some script written in Python 3.5. After I modified the PATH environment variable I wanted to install pandas module I'm gettint the following error:

```
C:\Python27>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run

    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_
files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare
_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 273, in popu
late_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 440, in find_requireme
nt
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 398, in find_all_candi
dates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 543, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 646, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 755, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 48
0, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 46
8, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 60
8, in send
    r.content
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 737,
 in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes
()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 660,
 in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\resp
onse.py", line 344, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\resp
onse.py", line 301, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py",
line 54, in read
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py", l
ine 297, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 281, in set
    return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\caches\file_cache
.py", line 99, in set
    with self.lock_class(name) as lock:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py", li
ne 19, in __init__
    LockBase.__init__(self, path, threaded, timeout)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py", line 24
2, in __init__
    hash(self.path)))
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 5: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Any ideas how to overcome this problem? I deleted the paths to Python 3.5 but it didn't help.

I also cannot install other packages.

Comment: That was the case. It resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know, I've converted my comment to an answer so cou can accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem while pip tries to create a lockfile in the cache directory, probably because your user home directory path where the cache is usually stored contains non-ascii characters.

As a workaround you can try to pass the `--no-cache-dir` option to pip, or explicitly pass a `--cache-dir` consisting of onyl ascii characters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all this but still get the same errors until I run the command

```
pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir
```

and run again the second command

```
pip install -U pip
```

and it's solved. Now I can install normally with

```
pip install <package_name> 
pip install -r <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading pip can often resolve issues like this, try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then attempt to reinstall pandas.

If that does not work there is a known bug in pip regarding unicode characters. More details can be found at the [pip github page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2501).

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error as previously when I attempt to upgrade pip.

Comment: Is it possible you have a unicode character in your path?

Comment: I guess not. It looks like this: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;D:\Users\michal_cisek\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Rtools\bin\

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

On Linux or macOS:

`pip install -U pip`

On Windows:

`python -m pip install -U pip`

Or you can use `conda install` as an alternative of `pip` :
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/full.html
....

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for more than two days and tried many methods. Nothing works
just install the lower version of python
It will do the trick.